A Question on limits
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable functions such that $f''$ and $g''$ are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f'(2) = 0$, $f''(2) \neq 0$, $g(2) = 0$ and $g''(2) \neq 0$. If
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{f'(x) g'(x)} = 1,$$
then

$f$ has a local minimum at $x = 2$

$f$ has a local maximum at $x = 2$

$f''(2) > f(2)$

$f(x) - f''(x) = 0$ for at least one $x \in \mathbb{R}$


My try
Since f'' is continuous, it means that f' possesses a continuous derivative, or we can say that f' is differentiable. Similarly, we can conclude that f is also differentiable. Same logic with g
Now, as $f'(2) = g(2)$, and since these functions are continuous, we can write:
$$\lim_{x \to 2} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 2} g(x).$$
From here using the information given in the question we can conclude that $$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2} g'(x).$$ as the functions are continuous we can write $$f(2)=g'(2)$$ also as f is positive gives g'(2) is also positive
I was not able to proceed any further. Also after I made these conclusions I started to think again and I found that for example x²,x both are 0 when x is 0 since these functions are continuous we could write  $$\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = \lim_{x \to 0} x.$$ but clearly their ratio is not 1(x²/x=x thus ratio of these limit is 0 not 1) but also I couldn't see any mistake in the reasoning that I did above but one might say as the limits are 0 we cannot divide but when we are taking limits we mean that its very close to 0 so why can't we just divide?
Please help me with this problem and also to find mistake in my conclusions
(Also I have knowledge only of things which are in the  syllabus of JEE ADVANCED)

'From here using the information given in the question we can conclude that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2} g'(x)$': You cannot cancel out zeros.

Given that $f'(2) = 0$ and $f''(2) \neq 0$, which implies $x = 2$ is either a maximum or a minimum but not an inflection point.
Also, Given  $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{f'(x) g'(x)} = 1$$
Applying L'Hopital rule,
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x)}{f''(x)g'(x) + g''(x)f'(x)} = \frac{f'(2)g(2) + g'(2)f(2)}{f''(2)g'(2) + g''(2)f'(2)} = 1$$
and $g'(2) = f(2) > 0$ since $f:R \to (0,\infty)$ and  $f'(2) = g(2) = 0$
$$\frac{g'(2)f(2)}{f''(2)g'(2)} = \frac{f(2)}{f''(2)} = 1$$ which implies,
$$f(2) - f''(2) = 0$$
Also, $f'(2) = 0$ and $f''(2) = f(2) > 0$ hence $x = 2$ is point of minimum.
